# input button occupying 100% in bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Input button occupying 100% in bootstrap div. I want see button and `<a>` next to each other. I don't know what's wrong here.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
     <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success " onclick="javascript: submitPhone();">
     <a class="linkbutton linkbutton" onclick="PostEditPhoneCancel()"> Cancel </a>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What you posted works fine (http://www.bootply.com/TuC12HJMa5). Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set the 'a' tag class as a button, instead of a link it already is.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happened because the elements have `display: block` applied.

There's a couple of solutions you can use.  One would be to use floats so apply `float:left` to both the button and the anchor.

Another way of achieving this is to add `display: inline-block` to both of the elements.